# How do I blit an image to a surface in pygame that's the same size as a Rectangle

Tags: python, image, pygame, blit, pygame-surface

I'm making a game with pygame and each Sprite has a rectangle and an image. How would I blit this image to a surface so that it's the same size as the rectangle?

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('My game')

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((250, 250, 250))

charRect = pygame.Rect((0,0),(10, 10))
print os.path.abspath("airbender.png")
charImage = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("ImageName.png"))
charImage = charImage.convert()

background.blit(charImage, charRect) #This just makes it in the same location
                                     #and prints it the same size as the image

screen.blit(background,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
```

Also why is that last `pygame.display.flip()` necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 480))
pygame.display.set_caption('My game')

background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill((250, 250, 250))

charRect = pygame.Rect((0,0),(10, 10))
print os.path.abspath("airbender.png")
charImage = pygame.image.load(os.path.abspath("ImageName.png"))
charImage = pygame.transform.scale(charImage, charRect.size)
charImage = charImage.convert()

background.blit(charImage, charRect) #This just makes it in the same location
                                     #and prints it the same size as the image

screen.blit(background,(0,0))
pygame.display.flip()
```